# UIKeyboardWillShowNotification - iOS8 vs iOS7

Tags: notifications, keyboard, ios8

With iOS8, I noticed that a view controller was no longer receiving a UIKeyboardWillSHowNotification, when it previously was with iOS7.

Here's the scenario:

1.) View Controller A is displaying a keyboard, and pushes View Controller B without resigning first responder

2.) View Controller B has a control that becomes first responder during its viewDidLoad call, while it's being created by VCA, before it's pushed onto the nav controller

3.) If VC A is NOT displaying a keyboard when pushing B, the notifications work fine.  However, if A is still editing when pushing B, then B does not get a keyboard will show notification.

Without the keyboard notification, VC B is not resizing / repositioning and does not look right.

---

The workaround I'm using until I find a solution is to do the following from any view controllers that might be editing when pushing another view controller that might be editing:

i.e., before pushing another view controller, be sure to call:
            [self.view endEditing:YES];

While it works, it doesn't seem good that the view controller (B) can be 'broken' by the state of the app prior to displaying it.

---

Question:  Am I doing something wrong here?

As far as I can tell, one of 3 things are possible:

A.) I *should* be getting the notifications, but I'm not b/c I'm doing something wrong

B.) I *should* be getting the notifications, but I'm not b/c of a bug

C.) I can't rely on always getting the notifications...But if I don't get the notifications in VC B when it appears, I need to be able to get the keyboard dimensions of the displayed keyboard without relying on the keyboard notification info.  All the apple docs say to use the notifications though (as far as I can find).... which points back to options A.) or B.).

---

I can create and upload sample code later tonight / early tomorrow to try and isolate / for you all to test/reproduce to see what I'm doing.

Answer (score 0):

I can see the same issue with iOS8 / xCode6 (works with iOS7 and xCode5). In my case, I'm observing a systemStatus property on the model in my AppDelegate so as to log the user out and bring the user back to the login screen when the user logs out from anywhere in the app. I'm doing that by setting the window.rootViewController to the loginViewController in my App Delegate observeValueForKeyPath: method.

This works fine on iOS7 / xCode5 but on iOS8 / xCode6, I loose the keyboard in the way. Looks like my loginViewController might be registering for keyboard notifications (in its ViewWillAppear method) before the window's rootViewController switch is complete (in iOS8) thus registering to the old window's notification center...

I moved the registration for keyboard notifications to the ViewDidAppear: method instead and that seems to fix it but somehow this seems to be called twice for some reason.